# Angular 5 value of text area can't be changed with directive

Tags: html, angular, directive

Here is the HTML:

```
<textarea expandTextArea class="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="What's on 
your mind, {{ UserInfo.firstname }}?" name="postbody"></textarea>
```

And here is the typescript code:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[expandTextArea]'
})
export class ExpandTextAreaDirective { 

    constructor() {}

    x: number = 0;

    @HostBinding('value') text: string = '';

    @HostBinding('rows') numRows: number = 2;

    @HostListener('focus') onFocus(eventData: Event) {
        this.numRows = 5;
    }

    @HostListener('blur') onBlur(eventData: Event) {
        this.numRows = 2;
        console.log(this.text);

    }
}
```

Why does the console log command ALWAYS show nothing as the value of the text area unless text is initialized to something else, but even then it still doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Because the textarea text is initially nothing. Try to add text={{ UserInfo.firstname }} in textarea tag and check if console.log show the text UserInfo.firstname.

Comment: console log prints the element and shows the firstname, but it doesn't show it on the screen

Comment: Try @HostBinding('value') text: string = UserInfo.firstname

Comment: I still want it to change when something is typed in the textarea.